# Is it possible to create a clojure type with a main method? (Using deftype, not gen-class)

Tags: clojure

The examples I've seen of main methods defined in clojure all use gen-class, together with (defn -main ...).  Is it possible to define a class with an executable main method using deftype?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is not possible, because interfaces (protocols) that *deftype* can implement cannot have static methods.

Answer (score -1):

A main method only makes sense if you AOT compile it (with gen-class or similar).

If you tried to define it in any other way, then it wouldn't be possible to use it since you would need to launch the clojure compiler / environment first. So you'd have to start the app by calling some other main() method instead.....